# I stirred the yeast and it said do not

Tags: yeast, barleywine

Making a British Barley wine and the **dry** yeast instruction called for sprinkling the  yeast on top of the starter. I was a bit over excited and stirred at some point after it reached room temp but before its expected use.

Problem or am I being a worry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a problem.  I've done that before and it had no negative effects.